# Pooled Mean Matching MICE

Tags: r, dplyr, imputation, r-mice

For MICE imputations I need to constrict the predictions so that the predicted values will have the same mean (which is a measured value). The situation is we are dealing with mean blood serum samples (individual blood samples are pooled together) where we have measured values, which are representative of the mean of those individuals. I am trying to predict what the concentration of x was in those individuals based on the measured mean and covariate data. You'll notice in my dummy dataset that there are 3 individuals (Individual_id) for each pool (Pool_id). So when imputing these values to the individuals we need the average of those 3 individuals to equal the Pool_mean.

How can we constrict the Mice algorithm to still predict based on covariate data, but have the means match exactly (can be any method chose, "cart", in this circumstance)? Could this conceptually be done through a MICE squeeze constraint with inputs from the mean?

The code is below:

```
library(mice)
library(dplyr)

#create demo data table as an example

Pool_id <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
Pool_mean <- c(15, 15, 15, 35, 35, 35, 42, 42, 42)
Individual_id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
concentration <- c(10, 20, NA, 30, NA,NA, NA, NA, 70)
co_variate <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3)

df <- data.frame(Pool_id, Pool_mean, Individual_id, concentration, co_variate)

#run mice to impute missing data

initial_imputed <- mice(df, m = 5, maxit = 10, meth = "cart", seed = 3985))
completed <- complete(intial_imputed)
```

I know that we can constraint mice using a post process and maybe a custom function like the vec_squeeze below. However, I need to constraint the values based on a mean. How could I update this function to create this?

```
vec_squeeze <- function(x, bounds) {
  stopifnot(length(x) == nrow(bounds))
  pmin(pmax(x, bounds[,1]), bounds[,2])
}
```

Comment: My intuition is that squeezing the imputed values isn't the right way to approach this. One option would be to use "Passive Imputation", to deterministically set the third value based on what the values of the first two were. See https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-knowledge.html#compositional-dataspadesuit for example. This might require rearranging to make sure missings are 3rd, but doable. Another option might be to try and write your own multivariate imputation method, since I don't think any of the built-in options will work. That's probably a better question for Cross Validated.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. After reviewing the document, it does make sense to create a passive imputation method. So looking at this, I want the mean of the individual_id to equal the Pool_mean to the Pool_id they correspond to. Would I script something like this for each?:

meth["concentration"] <- "~I(function(x, bounds){pmin(pmax(x, Pool_mean)} )"

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to use passive imputation on the 3rd variable to force the mean of the imputations to be equal to `pool_mean` from the data. First generate some data in 'wide' format.

```r
set.seed(123)
# Using larger example data to avoid issues with imputation models
n <- 20
pool_id <- rep(1:n, each = 3)
ind_id <- rep(1:3, times = n)
cov_1 <- sample(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), n*3, replace = TRUE)
cov_2 <- sample(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), n*3, replace = TRUE)
cov_3 <- sample(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3), n*3, replace = TRUE)
conc_1 <- round(rnorm(n*3, mean = 20 + 5*cov_1, sd = 5))
conc_2 <- round(rnorm(n*3, mean = 20 + 5*cov_2, sd = 5))
conc_3 <- round(rnorm(n*3, mean = 20 + 5*cov_3, sd = 5))
pool_mean <- apply(cbind(conc_1, conc_2, conc_3), FUN = mean, MARGIN = 1)
df <- data.frame(pool_id, ind_id, pool_mean, conc_1, conc_2, 
                 conc_3, cov_1, cov_2, cov_3)
df[which(rbinom(n*3, 1, prob = 0.5) == 1), "conc_3"] <- NA
df[which(rbinom(n*3, 1, prob = 0.2) == 1), "conc_2"] <- NA
df[which(is.na(df$conc_2)),"conc_3"] <- NA
head(df)
#>   pool_id ind_id pool_mean conc_1 conc_2 conc_3 cov_1 cov_2 cov_3
#> 1       1      1  18.00000     14     16     24   0.3   0.1   0.2
#> 2       1      2  24.33333     20     32     21   0.3   0.3   0.3
#> 3       1      3  16.33333     26     NA     NA   0.3   0.1   0.2
#> 4       2      1  25.00000     25     NA     NA   0.2   0.3   0.3
#> 5       2      2  22.00000     24     17     25   0.3   0.2   0.1
#> 6       2      3  22.00000     23     19     NA   0.2   0.3   0.3
```

I forced missing values into the third position to avoid re-arranging. I also have `ind_id` repeated within each `pool_id` instead of unique, but that's not important for what follows.

The key part of the passive imputation is `meth["conc_3"] <- "~ I((3*pool_mean) - conc_1 - conc_2)"`. If (A+B+C)/3 = D, then 3D - A - B = C.

```r
library(mice)
ini <- mice(df, maxit = 0, printFlag = FALSE)
# Limit the variables used in prediction, to avoid co-linearity
pred <- ini$predictorMatrix
pred[,] <- 0
pred["conc_1", c("pool_mean","cov_1")] <- 1
pred["conc_2", c("pool_mean","conc_1","cov_2")] <- 1

# Set the imputation methods. Use passive imputation for conc_3
meth <- ini$method
meth["conc_2"] <- "pmm"
meth["conc_3"] <- "~ I((3*pool_mean) - conc_1 - conc_2)"

# Control the visit sequence to ensure that conc_3 is updated
# after conc_2. Add other missing variables if needed.
visit_seq <- c("conc_2", "conc_3")
imps <- mice(df, method = meth,
             predictorMatrix = pred,
             visitSequence = visit_seq,
             printFlag = FALSE)
head(complete(imps, action = 1))
#>   pool_id ind_id pool_mean conc_1 conc_2 conc_3 cov_1 cov_2 cov_3
#> 1       1      1  18.00000     14     16     24   0.3   0.1   0.2
#> 2       1      2  24.33333     20     32     21   0.3   0.3   0.3
#> 3       1      3  16.33333     26     18      5   0.3   0.1   0.2
#> 4       2      1  25.00000     25     23     27   0.2   0.3   0.3
#> 5       2      2  22.00000     24     17     25   0.3   0.2   0.1
#> 6       2      3  22.00000     23     19     24   0.2   0.3   0.3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The imputation procedure has correctly replaced row 6's `conc_3` value with 24. The other rows have received a random imputation for `conc_2` and then had `conc_3` passively imputed. In general `conc_3` has no other restrictions on it. In row 3 `conc_3 = 5`, which may be questionably low. It could even become negative in some situations. Better modelling of `conc_2` would help.